# Form API, drupal_add_js() and setting a JS variable

Tags: forms, javascript

Consider

```
drupal_add_js(array(
  'radio86_media' => array('barfoo' => 'booboo')), 'setting'
);
```

and

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
  drupal_get_path('module', 'radio86_media') . '/select_media.js', 
);
```

These two 'lines' work well separately, but I think they could (and should) be combined so that the variable setting is set on the second line, combining the logic.

I've been fumbling around it and just can't get it to work. With this current way, I can console.log the `barfoo` variable via JS by using `Drupal.settings.radio86_media.barfoo` so it does work, but I really would like to have it combined.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I never tried, but I guess you can do it like that :

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
  array(
    'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'radio86_media') . '/select_media.js',
    'type' => 'file'
  ),
  array(
    'data' => array('radio86_media' => array('barfoo' => 'booboo')),
    'type' => 'setting'
  )
);
```

According the [documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) you should be able to add settings and files.

Comment: The select_media.js gets loaded just fine, but the variable is undefined. I tried swapping the arrays places so that the variable is created before the .js is included, but it did not help either.

Comment: I changed something in my code (just added `'type' => 'setting'` instead of `'setting'`. Can you try again ?

Comment: Worth a note that settings must have numeric keys. Weirdly. i.e. `$form['#attached']['js']['foo'] = ['data' => ['mysetting' => 1], 'type' => 'setting'];` does not work but `$form['#attached']['js'][] = ['data' => ['mysetting' => 1], 'type' => 'setting'];` does!