# Setting a Drupal.settings JS variable from a form field

Tags: 7, forms, javascript

i'm working on my first custom module and really fumbling along :). thanks in advance for your advice!

**goal**
i've added a checkbox to the comment form. if the user leaves it checked, then following comment insertion, i want to run some javascript on the following page.

**possible approach?** 
i've added the checkbox using hook_form_alter:

```
function wt_comments_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

//show the checkbox
  $form['wt_comments_share'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Post this comment on your Facebook wall too. Spread the word!'),
    '#default_value' => 1
  );
}
```

this works fine. **however**, i'm struggling to pass the variable from php to js. i read up on adding variables to Drupal.settings using drupal_add_js(), but i don't have a solid understanding of basic concepts. [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11716/form-api-drupal-add-js-and-setting-a-js-variable) seems to add values to Drupal.settings using #attached, but i couldn't figure out how to add the value of a normal form field.

i tried to run drupal_add_js() within hook_comment_presave or hook_comment_insert, to no avail:

```
function wt_comments_comment_insert($comment) {
  dpm( get_defined_vars() );

  //nothing
  drupal_add_js( array ("wt_comments" => $comment), 'setting');

  // nothing  
  drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', 'inline');
}
```

So i added the variable to the global $_SESSION object:

```
function wt_comments_comment_presave($comment) {
  $_SESSION['wt_comments'] = $comment->wt_comments_share;  
}
```

then, within a hook that *does* run drupal_add_js, i add the new session variable to drupal settings as described [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65920/store-session-variable-and-access-it-through-javascript/65921#65921):

```
function wt_comments_page_alter(&$page) {

  drupal_add_js("jQuery(document).ready(function () { 

      if ( Drupal.settings.wt_comments.wt_comments == 1 ) {

        // dance around! jQuery('body').css('background-color','green');

      }

    });",
    'inline'
  );

  //reset session variable
  $_SESSION['wt_comments'] = '0';

}
```

note: i wonder if hook_page_alter is the best choice here...

is this the right approach? thanks again folks!
-ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the value of the new field `wt_comments_share` to `$_SESSION['wt_comments']` is considered a good idea.

Because you're using session to pass values, you don't need to pass it to `Drupal.settings` unless if you want to add new JS file.

To add javascript code to node view you need to use `hook_init` or `template_preprocess_node`

```
function wt_comments_init() {
  // check if page is node and wt_comments is set
  if($node = menu_get_object() && isset($_SESSION['wt_comments'])) {
    // check users allowed to comment on this node
    if($node->comment) {
      // add javascript code
      drupal_add_js("jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
            if ( Drupal.settings.wt_comments.wt_comments == 1 ) {
              // dance around! jQuery('body').css('background-color','green');
            }
          });",
       'inline'
      ); 

      // unset session wt_comments
      unset($_SESSION['wt_comments']);
    }
  }
}
```